# can the JS decision making with 2 variables be reduced in any elegant way not with IF statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am a newbie JS developer and although the below code works perfectly fine with 2 variables and with IF statement but I want to know is there any elegant way of doing it WITHOUT IF statement.

The working code is below:

```
let animation;
    if(!detectScroll && !detectHover){
      animation = loadAnimation(reverseAnimationData)
    }
    else if(detectScroll && !detectHover){
      animation = loadAnimation(cyanAnimationData)
    }
    else if(!detectScroll && detectHover){
      animation = loadAnimation(cyanAnimationData)
    }
    else {
      animation = loadAnimation(cyanAnimationData)
    }
```

I want to know that can I reduce code into less lines of code with any other way without IF statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
let animation = loadAnimation(!detectScroll && !detectHover ? reverseAnimationData : cyanAnimationData )
```

Comment: It works for this scenario but how to tackle a more generic scenarios ?